# Property StackTrace cannot be assigned, it's read only

Tags: exception, enterprise-library

I have my Exception handler, which is used for enterprise library exception handling.
This handler contains method `HandleException`:

```
public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
        {

            Exception wrap = new Exception();
            wrap.StackTrace = exception.StackTrace;
            return wrap;
        }
```

When I try to assign received `exception.StackTrace` property to my variable `wrap`, I get Error:

```
property or indexer 'System.Exception.StackTrace' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

How I can assign it to  my variable?

Comment: You can't. It's readonly. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm trying to log properties, and in log file i see that StackTrace is unavailable, so i'm supposed to create handler which will writes all that i need

Comment: It looks like you're also trying to wrap the exception, so I wonder why you're trying to copy the stack trace.

Comment: The Enterprise library is where the enterprise and the real world collide with a rather heavy thud.  This compiler error is just another aspect of it, unclear thinking about what exceptions mean.  Failure in an enterprise is something that tends to be altered or hidden, it isn't enterprise compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically what I've seen.

```
    public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
    {

        //Do something with the Exception.

       return exception;
    }
```

or

```
    public Exception HandleException(Exception exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
    {

        ApplicationException appEx = new ApplicationException(exception.Message, exception);

       return appEx ;
    }
```